# Можно ли признавать за кем-либо вкус?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, лексическая-сочетаемость

*Нельзя не признавать за мной вкуса.*
Можно ли с помощью такой конструкции сказать о качестве, свойстве кого-либо?
В данном случае под "вкусом" понимается художественный вкус.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что можно. Такое управление все-таки имеется и используется.
В словаре Ушакова:
[призна́ть](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/972346)
2. *кого–что* или *что за кем–чем*. Выразить согласие на придание законной силы какому–нибудь порядку, положению, утвердить своим согласием право на существование кого–нибудь, чего–нибудь. *За ним признана слава блестящего оратора.*

*Признавать* (признать) *за мной вкус.

Нельзя не признавать* (признать) *за мной вкуса.*

Вкус — в значении "стиль", "чувство". Существительное имеет отвлеченное значение, поэтому при отрицании используется [родительный падеж](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr).

*Кто станет **признавать за собой ошибки**, чтобы «правда» Бори Бомштейна восторжествовала?* (В.Громов. Компромат для олигарха).

*Упереться и ни в коем случае **не признавать за собой** каких-либо серьезных **просчетов**, нельзя также публично клясться в любви к партии и ее высшему руководству ― сотрут в порошок* (М. А. Захаров. Театр без вранья).

*Этот язык был расшифрован лишь в начале XX в. Нам ничего не остаётся, как **признать за** предполагаемым **изобретателем** латыни поистине сверхчеловеческое **всезнание*** (А. А. Зализняк. Лингвистика по А. Т. Фоменко // «Вопросы языкознания», 2000).

Answer (score 0):

*"Нельзя не признавать за мной вкуса"* - фраза, на мой взгляд, неудачная. Нарушено управление - *признавать за мной*. Признавать можно что-то (не признавать чего-то), что-то каким-то.

Примеры с глаголом *признавать*:

*Самодовольная западная гуманистическая культура склонна признавать свой тип культуры универсальным и единственным, **не признает** существования разных типов культур, не ищет восполнения другими мирами.
Бердяев Н. А., Судьба России, 1917*

*История представлялась мне наполненной преступлениями и ложью, хотя я и **признавал** смысл истории и философию истории считал своей специальностью.
Бердяев Н. А., Самопознание, 1949*

Comment: Согласен, что фраза звучит неудачно, но канцеляритная "Нельзя не признавать у меня наличие вкуса", кажется, ещё хуже. К тому же мне непонятно, почему нельзя "признавать за" вкус, однако в классике множество примеров, когда "признают за" нечто столь же неотторжимое: "— Вы же сами признаете искренность за нашими женщинами" (Лесков), "...готовы были признать его за умнейшего человека" (Гоголь), "...тем не менее, за нею нельзя было не признать талантливой изобретательности..." (Писемский).

Comment: Отличные примеры, спасибо! Они очень кстати. Признаю Вашу правоту. Ответ, наверное, неудачный... Зато какое удачное к нему дополнение-замечание!) Всё к лучшему в этом лучшем из миров!.. Убрала свою неудачную правку предложения.